# Jsoup Getting specific data between different tags without class or tags

Tags: java, jsoup

Im trying to get the data of < "b" > #8 (with the random text).

right now i have this code that give me the TITLE that I need

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(""); 
Elements title = doc.select("div.column.two-third"); 
Element k = title.select("b").get(8);
```

but I also need the text. It is possible?

---

sample of the website's code Im trying to get data

```
<div class="column two-third"> 

<div style="color:#000000">                                   

<b>Title I dont want:</b> random text // "b" #0  </br>

<b>Title i dont want</b> random text // "b" #1  <br>

<b>Title i dont want:</b> random text // "b" #7  <br>

**<b>TITLE I WANT :</b> random text // "b" #8  <br>**

<div align="justify"> <br> <br>   <b style="color:#000000">text i dont want</b><br>
```

---

As you can see, the text that I want is in a Div without class or ID, also, the text is without tags ("p"). I just need #8. It is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible: the text after the `<b>` tag is in a text node. So after grabbing the correct `<b>` tag, jsoup let you select a specific node in the parent element with `.parent().childNode(int index)` (https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#childNode-int-) and gives you the index of the targeted `<b>` element with `.siblingIndex()`, so just get the childNode at the index incremented by 1.

**Example Code**

```
Elements bTags = htmlDocument.select("div.column.two-third > div b");

if(bTags.size()>8){
    Element title = bTags.get(8);
    String text = title.parent().childNode(title.siblingIndex()+1).toString();
    System.out.println(title.text() + "\n" + text);
}
```

**Output**

```
TITLE I WANT :
random text
```

Comment: thank you very much, this actually help resolve my problem. I dont know how to use "parents", "child" and node elements but with this I understand it a little more better.

Comment: @MrJaviiPR When you use chrome developer tools (f12), select an element in the Elements tab and switch in the additional panel from Styles to Properties to inspect the attributes of the DOM node, might be useful for understanding what jsoup is doing. Also read: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp. So the b tag is a node and the text afterwards is a node on the same level (sibling) and the nodes are in an ordered list, so the index of the text node is the index of the b tag raised by one. Hope this clears things up a bit.